# How should I run my Julia code using libjulia-openblas64 package on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, libraries, 20.10, julia-lang

I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed. Also I have simple program written in Julia language:

```
using LinearAlgebra
println(LinearAlgebra.BLAS.vendor())

M = 500;
c = [ sin(a + b.^2) for a in 1:M, b in 1:M]
t0 = time();
g = LinearAlgebra.eigvals(c);
t = time() - t0
println("t=", t)
m = maximum(real(g))
println("m=", m)
if M == 500
    @assert isapprox(m, 16.914886, rtol=1e-6)
end
```

I see interesting package in the repositories - [`libjulia-openblas64`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libjulia-openblas64). Its file list contains only [.so library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/libjulia-openblas64/filelist). I expect performance optimizations for running Julia code.
But when I install this package, I miss the `julia` executable. So the question is in the title.

---

```
$ dpkg -l | grep julia
ii  libjulia-openblas64:amd64                0.3.10+ds-3ubuntu1                  amd64        Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library (julia version)
$ julia
bash: julia: command not found
$ sudo apt-get install julia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjulia-openblas64 : Conflicts: libjulia1 (< 1.4.1+dfsg-2) but 1.4.1+dfsg-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
$ sudo aptitude install julia
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git{a} git-man{a} julia julia-common{a} less{a} libdsfmt-19937-1{a} liberror-perl{a} libgit2-28{a} libhttp-parser2.9{a} 
  libjulia1{a} libllvm8{a} libmbedcrypto3{a} libmbedtls12{a} libmbedx509-0{a} libopenlibm3{a} libutf8proc2{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 345 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjulia-openblas64 : Conflicts: libjulia1 (< 1.4.1+dfsg-2) but 1.4.1+dfsg-1 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                          
1)     libjulia-openblas64 [0.3.10+ds-3ubuntu1 (groovy, now)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really one should not try to use `libjulia-openblas64` package directly but should use default `julia` package which already contains OpenBLAS library and uses it.

Comment: I wonder why the package `libjulia-openblas64` is there.